# Iteration order

Tags: ruby

I'm working on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problem #4:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

My code as follows is wrong:

```
def ispalindrome?(number)
  number.to_s == number.to_s.reverse
end

palindromes = []
(100..999).each { |x|
  (100..999).each { |y|
    palindromes.push (x * y) if ispalindrome?(x * y)
  }
}   
palindromes.last # => 580085
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else said, replacing `palindromes.last` with `palindromes.max` will work.

The reason is that, as products of three-digit numbers, 580085 = 995 * 583 and 906609 = 993 * 913.

Think carefully about the order in which you consider pairs of `x` and `y`. If you consider `(993, 913)` and then later `(995, 583)` (as happens in the first and third examples), then the last palindrome found will be `580085`.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with ruby. Simple math :)

Replace `palindromes.last` with `palindromes.max`

Comment: Yep. That'll do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to sort your array before taking the value, I used your code from the first try just added

```
palindromes.sort
```

and it gave me 906609

Comment: Because it was first thing to come in mind, I'm not that expert in Ruby yet so I tend to forget existence of some functions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not returning the biggest number but the last number that was added , and it depends on the order you loop through the numbers.

you need to change your last command to:

```
puts palindromes.max
```